# Comparing the arguments passed to a macro

Tags: macros, expansion

I want to write a command which makes a norm of a vector, with following syntax: `\xnorm{v}`.

I want the norm delimiters to adapt to the size of the expression contained in `\xnorm{}`, BUT I want also an optional argument allowing to set the delimiter size manually. The concept is like this:

```
\newcommand{\xnorm}[2][adapt]{\LeftDelim{#1}\|\, #2\, \RightDelim{#1}\|}
```

where `\LeftDelim` expands to `\left` if the first argument is not given by the user and expands e.g. to `\Big` if the user give `\Big` in the first argument. Command `\RightDelim` is analogous.

But, it is just an idea. The problems come when implementing it. My try was as below:

```
\newcommand{\StringA}{adapt}
\newcommand{\StringB}{aaaaa} % This is temporary definition only, because this command is required to be well-defined.
\newcommand{\LeftDelim}[1]
{
\renewcommand{\StringB}{#1}
\ifx\StringA\StringB
\left
\else
#1
\fi
}
\newcommand{\RightDelim}[1]
{
\renewcommand{\StringB}{#1}
\ifx\StringA\StringB
\right
\else
#1
\fi
}
\newcommand{\xnorm}[2][adapt]{\LeftDelim\noexpand#1\|\, #2\, \RightDelim\noexpand#1\|}
```

Having the above, I use `\xnorm` as follows:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{dislpmaymath}
\xnorm[\Big]{X} \xnorm{\int_0^T}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

Question:

The first use of `\xnorm` above works correct, but the second generates the result equivalent to `adapt\|\int_0^T adapt\|`. It seems that the comparison of `\StringA` and `\StringB` failed in my macros. On the other hand, code

```
\begin{displaymath}
\LeftDelim{adapt}\| {\int_0^T} \RightDelim{adapt}\|
\end{displaymath}
```

generates the expected result - an integral sign with big norm delimiters. Thus, perhaps the problem is with expanding the argument for `\LeftDelim` and `\Rightdelim`. But I cannot figure what exactly should be changed. I have been manipulating a lot with `\expand` and `\expandafter` commands, with no positive result.

Comment: Well, I think you should have a look at the macros `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX` of [the package `mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools). Their purpose is exactly to create paired delimiters like your `\xnorm`.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. But I'm still interested in how to implement it by myself since I try to avoid extra packages. I believe that the solution isn't much more complex that the code snippet given in my question.

Comment: Well, `mathtools` is, IMHO, an unavoidable package. Just see what all "math" "tools" it provides. Maybe you'll find that it would have saved you hours of complicated LaTeX coding if you knew that.

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to use `\left` and `\right` by default. Really. You've been warned.

Now, the best thing you can do is to use `mathtools` and type

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\xnorm}{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

so that you'll be able to use

```
$\xnorm{v}$       % not expanding version
$\xnorm[\big]{v}  % slightly bigger
$\xnorm[\Big]{v}  % bigger
$\xnorm[\bigg]{v} % even bigger
$\xnorm[\Bigg]{v} % quite enormous
$\xnorm*{v}$      % self-adapting (with \left and \right)
```

If you want to implement it yourself and the wrong way, that is, with automatic `\left` and `\right` (did I say it's a bad choice? Well, it is), here's how

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xnorm}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
   {\left|#2\right|}%
   {\mathopen{#1|}#2\mathclose{#1|}}%
}
\makeatother
```

and call as before, with the difference you have no `*` version any more.

A better choice would be using `xparse`, that allows also for specifying an empty optional argument (with the above macro it would result in using `\left` and `\right`):

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xnorm}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\left|#2\right|}
    {\mathopen{#1|}#2\mathclose{#1|}}%
}
```

But do yourself a favor and use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and add `\left` and `\right` only when they're really necessary. Did I already say it?

Comment: 1. Ok, I have received the message - `\left` and `\right` are evil. But why?

Comment: 2. The simplicity of `\DeclarePaireDlimiter` is appealing. But is `mathtools` that common package? Many journals require not using odd packages when submitting a paper. Isn't it risky to use it and later be forced to correct manually whole TeX file?

Comment: @Gregory Compare `$a\left|x\right|$` and `$a\lvert x\rvert$`. Journals that don't want extra package don't want personal macros either.

Answer (score 3):

Please always post complete documents not fragments that have to be assembled, the you could test your example and avoid `\begin{dislpmaymath}`

The initial error was that you were never passing `#1` to your left and right macros you always passed the single token `\noexpand`

then in the case that you did not use `\left` and used `#1` (`\big`) you passed `\fi` rather than the delimiter as the argument to `\big` so things go very wrong. You need `\expandafter` and you *need* the `%` otherwise the token after `#` is a space token not `\fi`.

Note that this fixes the errors but still uses `\Big` on left and right, you will get better spacing if you used `\Bigl` on the left and `\Bigr` on the right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\StringA}{adapt}
\newcommand{\StringB}{aaaaa} % This is temporary definition only, because this command is required to be well-defined.
\newcommand{\LeftDelim}[1]
{
\renewcommand{\StringB}{#1}
\ifx\StringA\StringB
\left
\else
\expandafter#1%
\fi
}
\newcommand{\RightDelim}[1]
{%
\renewcommand{\StringB}{#1}%
\ifx\StringA\StringB
\right
\else
\expandafter#1%
\fi
}
\newcommand{\xnorm}[2][adapt]{\LeftDelim{#1}\|\, #2\, \RightDelim{#1}\|}


\begin{displaymath}
\xnorm[\Big]{X} \xnorm{\int_0^T}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```